# Parallelizing read-only operations on a single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a large df (approx several million rows) from which I would like to read data out to populate a couple of np.arrays. I want to parallelize this as it takes a long time, and I thought it would be rather straightforward to do so since it's **read-only operations on a single df**.

Previously I was relying on a pair of dictionaries to do lookups, but now I actually need additional functionality like `query()` and `groupby()`.

I have a custom object, lets call it df_interface which handles the communication to the df, so that the df itself is not replicated across different processes (causing memory issues). I have tried two approaches:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(args.nthreads) as executor:
    logging.info(f"Initiating the threadpool with {executor.__getattribute__('_max_workers')} threads")
    i = 0
    for short_row, long_row, is_hit, old_score, new_score in executor.map(_populate, train_combos):
        try:
            sums_arr[i] = short_row
            full_arr[i] = long_row
            target[i] = is_hit
            o_score[i] = old_score
            n_score[i] = new_score
            i += 1
            logging.info(f"Iter {i} done")

        except ValueError as e:
            logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
            logging.error(short_row, long_row, is_hit, old_score, new_score)
            input("Hit any key to continue")
```

In the case above, the execution is terribly slow, majority (87%) of the time goes to the `acquire` method of `_thread.lock`. I am guessing the access to the df_interface is causing all the waits.

To be sure I tried to eliminate the call to multiprocessing and do it all on a single process. It's faster than the previous but still not fast enough to be practically useful.

```
# trying the same without a threadpool
logging.info(f"Initiating without an executor")
i = 0
for short_row, long_row, is_hit, old_score, new_score in map(_populate, train_combos):
    try:
        sums_arr[i] = short_row
        full_arr[i] = long_row
        target[i] = is_hit
        o_score[i] = old_score
        n_score[i] = new_score
        i += 1
        logging.info(f"Iter {i} done")

    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
        logging.error(short_row, long_row, is_hit, old_score, new_score)
        input("Hit any key to continue")

sys.exit(0)
```

I can see from the profiler that the lions share (70%) goes to the `query()` method of the data frame, which is supposedly called 21435 times. This is particularly odd, as far as I can tell, it should be called no more than 5-6 times per element processed and I have been testing for 10 elements (full data is over 100K elements)

Is there a good way to solve this issue? Otherwise is using a pandas dataframe the wrong approach here?

Comment: You aren't using threading, you are using multiple processes, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, thats right... just a habit from java days. The question is still the same however.